# Prevent textbox autofill with previously entered values

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofill

I have an asp page with some Textbox controls on it.

By default, the browser will suggest previously entered values for each box.

I'd like to prevent that behavior for some of the textboxes.

Is there a way to reliably do that across all major browsers?

I've tried setting

```
AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
```

But that seems to have no effect in Firefox.

Here is an image of the behavior I'm trying to prevent.

[image]

Comment: Note it doesn't seem to be possible to turn autocomplete off in IE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328608/ie-11-explorer-textbox-autocomplete-off-is-not-working

Answer (score 82, accepted):

For firefox

Either:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Textbox1" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or from the CodeBehind:

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: the asp markup seems to throw a warning saying "The values permitted for this attribute do not include 'off'"  but adding the attribute as it shows in the second code blocks works!

Comment: The first line works for me, just ignore the warning :P

Comment: This got me where I needed to go.  For a Telerik RadTextBox it's `<telerik:RadTextBox ... AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />`.

Answer (score 11):

> Autocomplete need to set off from textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: as my comments above state, this no longer seems to work.  need to do it via code using the Attributes.Add as shown above

Answer (score 11):

> By making AutoCompleteType="Disabled",

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_userid" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

> By setting autocomplete="off",

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_userid" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

> By Setting Form autocomplete="off",

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">  
    //your content  
    </form>
```

> By using code in .cs page,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {  
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
        {  
            txt_userid.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");  
        }  
    }
```

> By Using Jquery

```
    <head runat = "server" >  
        < title > < /title> < script src = "Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" > < /script> < script type = "text/javascript" >  
        $(document).ready(function()  
        {  
            $('#txt_userid').attr('autocomplete', 'off');  
        });  
    //document.getElementById("txt_userid").autocomplete = "off"  
    < /script>
```

> and here is my textbox in ,

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_userid" ></asp:TextBox>
```

> By Setting textbox attribute in code,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {  
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
        {  
            txt_userid.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Setting AutoCompleteType="Disabled" didn't work in SharePoint web part, it didn't render anything. I don't know why. But setting autocomplete="off" did work.

Answer (score 7):

This is the answer.

```html
<asp:TextBox id="yourtextBoxname" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

> AutoCompleteType="Disabled"

If you still get the pre-filled boxes for example in the Firefox browser then its the browser's fault. You have to go

> 'Options' --> 'Security'(tab) --> Untick

'Remember password for sites and click on Saved Passwords button to delete any details that the browser has saved.

This should solve the problem

Comment: Can you explain him why does it work so he can learn from it?

Answer (score 6):

Trying from the CodeBehind:

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding `autocomplete="new-password"` to the password field did the trick. Removed auto filling of both user name and password fields in Chrome.

```
<input type="password" name="whatever" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

Comment: This was the only solution that did worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that for Chrome to work properly it needs to be `autocomplete="false"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
        c.select =
        function (event, ui) 
        { this.value = ""; return false; }
    </script>
```