# Disabling autocomplete for textbox within ModalpopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a modalpopupextender to add new users in an application. The extender has username and password textboxes. I do not want these textboxes to be autopopulated by values as these are suppose to be new values not the old used ones. I tried setting:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="userNameTextBox" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None">
```

and also Disable but nothing works.

What am I missing? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your code :

asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off">

you can also check this link [autocomplete off link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686224/prevent-textbox-autofill-with-previously-entered-values/20016509#20016509)

Comment: Does not work. in fact off in not available, does not compile.

Comment: Sorry it does work!! I was putting AutocompleteType="off". Thanks a lot!!