# IE 11 Explorer TextBox autocomplete=”off” is not working

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am developing asp.net web site.And I add `autocomplete=”off”` property forms and objects but is not working.I tried lots of way but none is working.In IE 10 , IE 9 , it is working , but in IE 11 it is not working.Can any one please help me about this.

Comment: Please share us what have you tried

Answer (score 3):

IE11 ignores this attribute on purpose. See IE11 list of changes here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/24/internet-explorer-11-changelist-change-log.aspx .