# Disable browser's autocomplete textboxes in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to disable browser's autocomplete effect on all textboxes in asp.net c# application. I have tried following jquery but it doesn't works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: In what way does it not work? not at all? not for some? not always?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: use <input type="text" name="txt" autocomplete="off">

Comment: @ALL I have tried all the ways but didn't work for me

Comment: Read [ask], read comments, **respond**. Then, maybe, you'll get your answer.

Comment: @user2179026 With which browsers have you tried? (`autocomplete` behavior depends on browser implementations)

Comment: [How to turn off autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)  give a fairly concise overview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686224/prevent-textbox-autofill-with-previously-entered-values

Answer (score 1):

Add autocomplete="off" attribute in input control.

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="name" type="text" name="name">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c#, you can use this code inside the form. This will disable all the controls autocomplete inside the form.

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

If you want to disable individually, you can use this code.

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or you can change the autocomplete at run time:

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ViewStateMode` property of the textbox to Disabled . Should work for you.