# Prevent Textbox from showing history

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am designing a simple asp:TextBox, but the input may contain sensitive data. How can I prevent the textbox from displaying previous values entered?

Comment: Have you tried adding autocomplete=off to the form?

Comment: I saw a similar question suggest that, but AutoComplete is not available for asp:TextBox. There is AutoCompleteType, but it doesn't appear to be the same thing.

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686224/prevent-textbox-autofill-with-previously-entered-values. According to the accepted answer, the `autocomplete` attribute can be set in code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for the link - it worked. Is there any reason the intellisense didn't recognize AutoComplete as a valid field?

Comment: The ASP.NET probably does not implement that attribute of the underlying HTML element. When that happens, you can add the attribute "by hand" to the `Attributes` collection of the control.