# Chrome autofill my first textbox with UserName

Tags: asp.net

Chrome Autofill my first textbox in every page with logged user name. I tried different method like

`autocomplete="off"`

> But this is not working.

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="200px" Text=""  >`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

Comment: No.How to stop chrome to autofill my textbox?

Comment: Stop using form fields [a nice read](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451#c99).

Comment: Please see this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686224/prevent-textbox-autofill-with-previously-entered-values

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you make a hidden `Textbox` with the `name` and `id` username or email.

Update:
Chromium should be ashamed.
Sadly, they didn't fix the problem and may do so in the near future. See the links below:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451&can=2&q=Autofill%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

As a result, it seems the only practical, if not perfect, solution. Chromium ignores hidden TextBoxes (display: none) so it won't work. I suggest hiding the fake userName TextBox with zero width or height or positioning it outside the browser viewport.

This is an example:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" style="position: fixed; font-size: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; top: -500px; left: -500px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuJho.png)

Please make this as below in code behind.

txtSearch.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");

you can check attached screenshot.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Please amend your answer to include the related piece of functionality.

Comment: Ok, will take care next time, Thanks

Comment: I have implement this code and it's working fine thanks!