# I am having a problem with the login page. The login name text box is acting like a dropdown list. How can I stop this?

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I am creating a website. It requires users to login.

When I click on the Username text box, as soon as I enter the first letter of the name it turns into a drop down list displaying every name ever entered, that starts with that letter!

I have found a lot of articles on how to accomplish this, but none how to PREVENT this from happening.

I want the text box to act like a text box.

I am using .NET version 4.62

I have searched here and there are many questions about making this happen, I could find none on how to stop it.

If you know how to stop this from happening, and can reply with the answer, I will be forever grateful.

The ASPX of the form is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="Crescent._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server" link= "stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Default" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="54px"         
ImageUrl="Images/CrescentLogo2007.bmp"  Width="175px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" top="1px" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" 
            Text="Call us at 1-800-560-7867" CssClass="style2"></asp:Label>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
        


</div>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Text="Log In"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
        Height="25px" Text="User Name:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" cache=" "></asp:TextBox>
         
</p>
<p>
   
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="margin-left:5px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-    
Size="Small" 
        Height="25px" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" style="margin-left: 5px" 
        Width="164px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:button runat="server" text="Login" style="margin-left: 58px" 
        Width="153px" ID="btnLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
</p>       
   
   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the autocomplete property of the control set to?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686424/9365244